# Do 2 different Availability Zones in EC2 act as a WAN or a LAN?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, availability-zone

I am trying to establish a RabbitMQ Cluster on EC2 over 2 availability zones.
In its docs, RabbitMQ mentions to avoid network partition on the cluster nodes.

Do 2 different Availability Zones in EC2 act as a WAN or a LAN?
Can anyone direct me to a link?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

RabbitMQ cluster is not recommended in case of WAN network (say 2 Regions) . But the connection between availability zones can be viewed as a LAN. 
We running RabbitMQ cluster in differnt AZ's with no issues.

AWS doesn't tells you how far away each AZ from each other, but you can assume it's close enough to be viewed as a LAN. One of the characteristics of a LAN is `Coverage area is generally a few kilometers.`

Comment: Thanks,   
Regarding  "but you can assume it's close enough to be viewed as a LAN". Can I see it in the Docs. I can't find anywhere that mentions it.